# I would like to show points moving on a map by date

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, cartography, geolocation

I would like to create a map where I can see points moving. 
I have table of points for example with a date column,

```
A 01/01/2012
B 02/01/2012
C 03/01/2012 
D 04/01/2012
E 05/01/2012
F 06/01/2012
```

I would like to show them date after date ( `01/01/2012`, `02/01/2012`...):
First screen we will see only the point A,
second screen will show us B ...

How can we do it? I am using QGIS and Mapinfo.

Answer (score 3):

That's possible using [QGIS Time Manager](http://underdark.wordpress.com/projects/time-manager/) plugin.

It will be necessary to convert the timestamps to YYYY-MM-DD format first though.